# cakephp Virtual Field in SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I am trying to work with cakephp virtualFields in cakephp 1.3. My sql query is as follows but I need day_index (my virtual fields)  to be 'DAYOFWEEK(start_date)'.

I need to rewrite a query

```
$data = $this->Calendar->query("SELECT *, DAYOFWEEK(start_date) as day_index, TIME(start_time) as time 
    FROM calendars WHERE calendar_category_id =$cal ORDER BY day_index, time");
```

into this format:

```
$sqlConditions = array("Calendar.calendar_category_id"=>$cal);
$sqlOrderBy = array("Calendar.day_index", "Calendar.time asc");
$sqlParams = array('conditions'=>$sqlConditions,'order'=>$sqlOrderBy);
$data = $this->Calendar->find('all',$sqlParams);
$this->set('data',$data);
```

So I'm not sure how to/where to put or declare the virtual field.

```
$fields = $this->Calendar->virtualFields['day_index'].'AS 'DAYOFWEEK(start_date)';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found 2 ways to do this, not sure if one is better than the other.
**controller edit only method**

```
$sqlFields = array("DAYOFWEEK(Calendar.start_date) as day_index",
    "TIME(Calendar.start_time) as time",
    "Calendar.start_date",
    "Calendar.calendar_category_id",
    "Calendar.start_time");
    $sqlConditions = array("Calendar.calendar_category_id"=>$cal);
    $sqlOrderBy = array("Calendar.day_index, Calendar.time asc"); 
    $sqlParams = array('fields'=>$sqlFields,'conditions'=>$sqlConditions,'order'=>$sqlOrderBy);
    $data = $this->Calendar->find('all',$sqlParams);
    return $data;
    exit();
```

**model method with edits to controller based on this method**
**Model >**

```
var $virtualFields = array(  
   'day_index' => "DAYOFWEEK(Calendar.start_date)",
   'time' => "TIME(Calendar.start_time)"
 );  
 var $displayIndex = 'day_index'; 
 var $displayTime = 'time';
```

**Controller >**

```
$sqlConditions = array("Calendar.calendar_category_id"=>$cal);
    $sqlOrderBy = array("Calendar.day_index, Calendar.time asc"); 
    $sqlParams = array('conditions'=>$sqlConditions,'order'=>$sqlOrderBy);
    $data = $this->Calendar->find('all',$sqlParams);
    return $data;
    exit();
```